# passing 2D array of structure to a function

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, structure, argument-passing

this is my structure
struct lookup

```
{
   char action;
   int state;
};
```

value of rows and columns are known but they are read from a file.

```
main()   
{
   // other initialization...then
   lookup* table[rows][columns];
   for (int i = 0; i < rows;i++)
   {    
        for (int j = 0; j < columns;j++)
        {   
             table[i][j]=new (lookup);
        }
   }
}
```

then i assigned values to each element of table
now i want to pass this table to another function for further operations
say,

```
void output(lookup* table)
{
     // print values stored in table 
}
```

how can i pass the table with all its content to output() function from main()??
thanks for help..

Comment: Since this is C++ you should really use `vector` and avoid `new` when possible.

Comment: Thats not a 2D array of structures; its a 2D array of pointers.

Comment: Wrap it in a struct and pass that in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare parameter as double pointer (pretend you receive an 1-dimensional array of pointers). Since such array lies in memory contiguously, you can compute position of current element.

```
void output(lookup** table, int rows, int cols)
{
  lookup* current_lookup = NULL;
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
  {   
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
      current_lookup = table[i*cols + j];
      printf("Action: %c, state: %d\n", current_lookup->action, current_lookup->state);
    }
  }
}
```

You call it by passing first element of an array:

```
int main()   
{
   lookup* table[rows][columns];

   //....

   output(table[0]);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Nabla I silently assumed existence of proper operator in the global scope :) Answer updated with more common and 'independent' form of printing.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek - i am getting compilation error
error: cannot convert ‘lookup* (*)[(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)columns) + -1)) + 1)]’ to ‘lookup***’ for argument ‘4’ to ‘void output(int, int, int, lookup***)’
  output(rows,columns,final,table); 
                                 ^

Comment: This is flat-wrong. A 2D array of `Type` (i.e. `Type ar[N][M]` is *not*  is not equivalent in representation or implementation to `Type **ar` *at all*. The latter provides syntactic sugar, but they're *not* the same.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek i am able to get the values but they are not in order now.But, thanks for your help.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek but now its giving segmentation fault.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek it should be table[i*cols+j]